# Linguistic schemes got removed from old devices

Tags: ios, nslinguistictagger

I'm using NSLinguisticTagger for my application and it was working fine across all devices with iOS 11 and above. Recently, the 2 older devices (6s and iPad mini) stopped recognizing the tags, only returned "Other" tag.

On a different thread, someone said that "Somehow my phone felt I "didn't need" all the schemes and got rid of them one day. I uninstalled English then added it again and now it works". So I tried it and it worked on both devices. (I just switched from English U.K to English U.S) but I don't think that the chosen language itself matters.

I can't reproduce the issue anymore since it's fixed, but really want to know WHY that solution fixed that??

Comment: I guess is a result of saving space optimization